# Detect Firebase initial on(value) completion

Tags: firebase

I'm using `ref.on("value", myfunc)` when I initialise my app to retrieve all my data from FB. Since there's quite a bit of data to retrieve, I want to show a loading symbol until `myfunc` actually gets run.

Is there any way to do this? The only way I can think of right now is:

1. First run a `hasChildren` on the relevant FB node to check if there is data to be received.
2. If there is, display a loading image.
3. Once the `on` listener calls `myfunc` then hide the loading image.

I am just wondering if Firebase provides a more graceful way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I am misunderstanding what you are doing, but I don't think you even need to call `hasChildren`. The callback function you pass to `ref.on()` will be called even if there are no children at that location.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/92uabp30/7/

I think this is similar to what you are doing. Here I have a "Loading..." `div`, and an "output" `div`:

```
function getMyData(){
    $("#loading").show();
    $("#output").hide();

    new Firebase("https://examples-sql-queries.firebaseio.com/user/999").on('value', show);
}
```

And the callback function:

```
function show(snap) {
    $('pre').text(JSON.stringify(snap.val(), null, 2));
    $("#output").show();
    $("#loading").hide();
}
```

If you check `https://examples-sql-queries.firebaseio.com/user/999`, you will see that it is empty. When you run the example, you will see that the callback function is called anyway.

Comment: You're right - I hadn't realised that the callback gets run even if the node is empty. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I missed the obvious solution. Passing a callback function to `myfunc` means that I can initiate a loading image and remove it when the callback function is run.